# Using Grails Exector Plugin's runAsync , Why do I need a transaction to save a Domain object?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-orm, executor

Here's roughly what I'm doing in a service:

```
runAsync 
{
  <some work here>
  myDomainObject.merge()     
}
```

I get an error saying "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here". I know for sure that the code is being run asynchronously, so it would seem that the Executor Plugin is setup correctly.

So I tried this next, thinking the domain object "myDomainObject" must not be bound in this thread although the thread has a hibernate session thanks to the executor plugin:

```
runAsync
{
  <work>
  def instance2= MyDomainObject.get(myDomainObject.id) // works
  instance2.field1=123
  instance2.save() // fails
}
```

I get the same error here and interestingly, the get() succeeds in bringing the correct data and setting it to instance2. It's only the "save()" that fails. I know this because I've stepped through the code in a debugger.

Finally, if I do the following, everything works:

```
runAsync 
    {
      <some work here>
      MyDomainObject.withTransaction {
           myDomainObject.field1=123
           myDomainObject.merge()
      }
    }
```

I don't understand why this transaction is required since I haven't set the service I'm writing the above code in to be transactional. I know there must be something fundamental that I don't know here, but I can't find out what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you answered your own question :)

*I don't understand why this transaction is required since **I haven't set the service I'm writing the above code in to be transactional**.*

Have a look at the [NOTE ON TRANSACTIONS](https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor#usage). You need your service to be transactional.

> NOTE ON TRANSACTIONS: keep in mind that this is spinning off a new
>   thread and that any call will be outside of the transaction you are
>   in. Use .withTransaction inside your closure, runnable or callable to
>   make your process run in a transaction that is not calling a
>   **transactional** service method (such as when using this in a
>   controller).

**UPDATE**
Try the service class like below:

```
class MyService{

    def someMethod(){
        runAsync {
            anotherMethod()
        }
    }

    def anotherMethod(){ 
       <work>
       def instance2= MyDomainObject.get(myDomainObject.id) // works
       instance2.field1=123
       instance2.save() // should work as well
    }
}
```

Comment: So here's the part I don't understand :" any call will be outside of the transaction you are in."  I didn't think I was in a transaction. Or is it that all Services in Grails are auto transactions?

Comment: Yes, all services in Grails are transactional by default unless you specify `static transactional = false`. See my update. @TriArc

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the nature of services @dmahapatro. However, I don't see the difference between what I had done in my second try (shown in my post above), and what you've shown in the update. The code I showed got rid of anotherMethod() for simplicity, but that's exactly what I did in my code and I got the same error. Why would having another method help in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @TriArc Is your service transactional? Are you using `@Transactional` on any of its method?